# Matching double space in regular expression string with BootstrapValidator

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/regexp/ and I want to validate a name (not a person). The name must only consist of letters, numbers and one or more single spaces (not in the beginning or end). The minimum length is 3 characters. I have this regular expression:

`^[^\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s!]{3,}[^\s]$`

My PHP code:

```
echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='fullname'";
echo "required";
echo "data-bv-regexp='true'";
echo "data-bv-regexp-regexp='^[^\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s!]{3,}[^\s]$'";
echo "data-bv-regexp-message='Your current input is not valid' />";
```

My examples of text (underscore is spaces):

`Name` should validate OK.

`My___Name` should fail.

`_My_Name_` should fail.

`My_Name_Is_OK` should validate OK.

My questions:

1) How do I avoid the double/multiple spaces in the middle of the text?

2) And why do I need to type in 5 characters for it to validate OK? I can of course change this to `{1}` and then it will validate OK, but it is not logical to me (what if I only wanted 1 character to validate OK)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to use `[^\s]` at the start/end of the regex because it would match *any* non-whitespace character, not just `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (why is there a `!` in your character class, by the way?). Note: `\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]`.

I also suspect you don't want to allow tabs, newlines, formfeeds and other whitespace characters (which `\s` contains), so use a plain space character instead.

Then, your regex currently requires a minimum of 5 characters, not three - `[^\s]` matches one, `[a-zA-Z0-9\s!]{3,}` matches three or more, and `[^\s]` matches one more.

To avoid double spaces, you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.* {2})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

should do what you need.

**Explanation:**

```
^              # Start of string
(?!.*[ ]{2})   # Assert that there are no two consecutive spaces
[a-zA-Z0-9]    # Match one alphanumeric character
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+  # Match one or more alphanumeric characters or spaces
[a-zA-Z0-9]    # Match one alphanumeric character
$              # End of string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/yI5cU2/1).

Comment: +1 for good explanation, live-test and this works perfectly. The `!` was a leftover from some old test and I didn't even notice it